# DNS Server Commands

Tags: python, sockets, dns, router

I use socket module in python to connect to dns server on a router.The connection is succesful and if I send a message I get a blank reply but what are commands that I can write to dns server?

```
Router is a Huawei Hg552e
gateway: 192.168.1.1
dns server port: 53
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The commands are not clear-text, so you need to read the protocol specification and implement it, or use a library that already implements that for you, for example, [PyUnbound](https://www.unbound.net/documentation/pyunbound/).

See [RFC 1035 - DOMAIN NAMES - IMPLEMENTATION AND SPECIFICATION](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt).